# Why does an Android app project have to include a package used by a library

Tags: android, android-library

An Android app uses a library (aar module) that uses "com.google.gson.Gson".  The library has the following in its build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

The app builds fine, but generates the following error when it starts:

```
Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/Gson;
```

The only way to solve it is adding the same compile line to the app's build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

**[Edit]**

The library was added with [the standard procedure](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) that created a folder under the app called "androidLibrary-release". The following line has been added to the build.gradle of the app:

```
compile project(':androidLibrary-release')
```

Comment: can you specify the library?

Comment: "An Android app uses a library" -- how? Is the library published to a Maven-style repo, and the app is referencing it from there? Is the library being used by `compile project(':modulename')`? Are you doing something else?

Comment: Yes, the library is used by compile project(':modulename').  @mayosk I will edit the post by adding how the library is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries don't include their dependencies.  It is up to the developer to include them as necessary in the app modules that implement them. However, if this library comes from a Maven repo, it is possible to include the information about which dependencies the library uses and they will be fetched when your project is built.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The app does not use com.google.code.gson:gson directly.  Only some classes of the library use it.

Comment: @Hong you will still need to add the dependency if you want it to work correctly.

Comment: This is a bit strange because the library has many other dependencies. The app will crash only when the app uses the methods of the library using a dependency not included in the app.  This means an app will rely on crashes to find out which additional dependencies should be added.

Comment: @Hong well it should rely on proper documentation, not crashes. Please mark the answer as correct if it was useful.

Comment: This is unfortunate.  I assume using jar library does not have this problem because I have never experienced this issue with numerous jar libraries that I have used.  I don't why aar cannot do the same.

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt Could you please provide the source of your statement?! I'm facing the same problem and would like to get a better understanding of the background.